Idiomatic Golang Concurrent Pipeline
After watching talks (namely Robs Pikes talk) and reading more about golang's approach to concurrency and the intended architecture of highly concurrent systems. I wanted to see if I could abstract it a little to manage the channels and go routines in a more central way.
I wrote this pipeline abstraction and wanted to know if it has any memory leak / deadlock or inherent performance tradeoffs compared to starting and managing the channels and goroutines yourself.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var (
    rounds = 500
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    steps := []Step{
        {name: "download asset", factor: 20, depth: 1000, Transformer: Transformer{do: func(ctx context.Context, data interface{}, err error) (interface{}, error) {
            strData, ok := data.(string)
            if !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected string but got %T", data)
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(rand.Int()%1000))
            return strData, nil
        }}},
        {name: "build assets", factor: 20, depth: 1000, Transformer: Transformer{do: func(ctx context.Context, data interface{}, err error) (interface{}, error) {
            strData, ok := data.(string)
            if !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected string but got %T", data)
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(rand.Int()%1000))
            return strData, nil
        }}},
        {name: "save to dropbox", factor: 20, depth: 1000, Transformer: Transformer{do: func(ctx context.Context, data interface{}, err error) (interface{}, error) {
            strData, ok := data.(string)
            if !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected string but got %T", data)
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(rand.Int()%1000))
            return strData, nil
        }}},
    }

    pipeline := NewPipeline(ctx, steps)

    timer := utils.Start()
    pipe := pipeline.Start()
    defer pipe.Terminate()

    for i := 0; i < rounds; i++ {
        go func(j int) { pipe.Input <- strconv.Itoa(j) }(i)
    }

    for i := 0; i < rounds; i++ {
        <-pipe.Output
    }
    timer.StopNPrint("pipeline")
}

type Step struct {
    name string

    factor int
    depth  int

    Transformer
}

type Transformer struct {
    do func(context.Context, interface{}, error) (interface{}, error)
}

func NewPipeline(ctx context.Context, steps []Step) Pipeline {
    var p Pipeline

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

    p.ctx = ctx
    p.cancel = cancel
    p.Steps = steps
    p.Errors = make(chan PipelineError)

    for i := 0; i < len(steps); i++ {
        p.Intermediary = append(p.Intermediary, make(chan interface{}, steps[i].depth))
    }

    p.Intermediary = append(p.Intermediary, make(chan interface{}, 1))
    p.Input = p.Intermediary[0]
    p.Output = p.Intermediary[len(p.Intermediary)-1]

    return p
}

func (p *Pipeline) Start() Pipeline {
    go p.terminationListener()
    for i := range p.Steps {
        for j := 0; j < p.Steps[i].factor; j++ {
            go func(s Step, i int) {
                for {
                    select { // try to read val from chan
                    case <-p.ctx.Done():
                        return // the channel is closed, return
                    case read, ok := <-p.Intermediary[i]:
                        if !ok {
                            return // channel is closed, return
                        }
                        response, err := s.do(p.ctx, read, nil)
                        if err != nil {
                            p.Errors <- PipelineError{Err: err, From: s.name, Input: read}
                        }
                        select { // try to write to channel until it accepts, or the channel is closed
                        case p.Intermediary[i+1] <- response:
                            // successfully sent the response
                        case <-p.ctx.Done():
                            // the context is cancelled, stop processing
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }(p.Steps[i], i)
        }
    }
    return *p
}

func (p *Pipeline) Terminate() {
    p.cancel()
}

func (p *Pipeline) terminationListener() {
    <-p.ctx.Done()
    for i := range p.Intermediary {
        close(p.Intermediary[i]) // close them from input -> output to avoid deadlocks
    }
}

type PipelineError struct {
    Err   error
    From  string
    Input interface{}
}

type Pipeline struct {
    Input        chan interface{}
    Output       chan interface{}
    Intermediary []chan interface{}
    Errors       chan PipelineError
    Steps        []Step
    ctx          context.Context
    cancel       context.CancelFunc
}


Please, don't post the same question on multiple sites of the Stack Exchange network (please read).
